# Equivalent method to Bloomberg BlpDataClass.get_BLPSubscribe

Tags: c#, bloomberg, currency-exchange-rates

As I am migrating Bloomberg **COM based dll** to Bloomberg **API v3** in .Net, I am facing some issue in matching up the Equivalent method.
I tried fetching using `ReferenceDataRequest` for the security *LMCADP 20150819 COMDTY*, but prices are not matching.
Please suggest which type request should be used.

```
private void sendRefDataRequest(Session session)
    {
        Service refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
        Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");

        // Add securities to request
        Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");

        for (int i = 0; i < d_securities.Count; ++i)
        {
            securities.AppendValue((string)d_securities[i]);
        }

        // Add fields to request
        Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
        for (int i = 0; i < d_fields.Count; ++i)
        {
            fields.AppendValue((string)d_fields[i]);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("Sending Request: " + request);
        session.SendRequest(request, null);
    }
```

and added securities

```
if (d_securities.Count == 0)
        {
            d_securities.Add("IBM US Equity");
            d_securities.Add("LMCADP 20150819 COMDTY");
        }
```

Comment: what results did you get with the COM API? What results do you get with API V3? What fields are you requesting?

Comment: Fields that i am passing `if (d_fields.Count == 0)
   {
    d_fields.Add("PX_LAST");
   }`

Comment: Example for **Bloomberg API** PX_Last is coming **5298.25** and from **COM library**  i am getting **5380.15**

Comment: HP shows 5298.25 - not sure where the 5380.15 price is coming from... Have you asked HELP HELP?

Answer (score 0):

BLPSubscribe in Bloomberg's old ActiveX control made either a synchronous subscription or static request depending on the fields you passed in.
If you were requesting static fields like PX_LAST then a ReferenceDataRequest would be the appropriate way to obtain the data.

If you were looking at the realtime field LAST_PRICE, however, you would want to make a subscription (build a SubscriptionList out of Subscription objects and then use Session.Subscribe(..)).